# Integrate user authentication with Push API

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, openid-connect, service-worker

In a webapp I am currently using an OpenID Connect token to authenticate users. I am now looking into using a Services Worker and Push API to do notifications. I understand that I need to register the service worker with the messaging provider (FCM) then send the client information to the app server so it can send messages through the provider. What I don't understand is how I prevent the client devices from receiving notifications if the user has logged out.

extra info:
The existing webapp uses IdentityServer 4 for the authorization server and oidc-client in the client.

I read that FCM has its own token you can delete to stop notifications but what if that code fails or the OpenID Connect token expires while the client isn't open (background notifications), what would preventing the server from sending notifications to the browser with stateless authentication.

TLDR
With to dis-joined systems: OpenID Connect that authenticates users, and FCM that authenticates devices. How do I make them work together?

Comment: Hi William. It's kinda hard to tell what you're asking here. Are you asking for a good process (*what to do*) when the user logs out or how to delete the token to avoid getting notifications? Also, if you have any related code snippets already, do include it in your post. Cheers!

Comment: I'm looking for a good process for implementing push notifications to a system with authorization already implemented. Without having two disconnected systems. (one user/token based and one device based)

Comment: @AL. How would deleting the token avoid getting notifications?

Comment: Deleting the token invalidates it. If the token is invalid, FCM won't send a message to it.

Comment: I'v been referring to the openid connect token. I just read up on FCM uses a token to. But still what if the openid connect token expires while the client code isn't running or the code fails to delete the FCM token while the user is logging out. You'd end up with an unauthenticated user getting notifications.

Comment: Hi @WilliamLohan, how did you solve the issue with preventing unauthenticated user getting notifications? I'm saving the FCM token to user profile in Firestore DB when user authenticates, but when user signs out, I can't be sure that removing the token from DB will always succeed. Did you come up with some other way?